# Weekday function error with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have dates within a cell using this format: (08/12/2015  00:00:00), which the function works.
The other cells have this format: (8/19/2015 0:00) which the function doesnt work.

When I try to use "WEEKDAY(8/19/2015 0:00)" I get #VALUE!
Any ideas?

Comment: That's not how you use the [`WEEKDAY()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a) function.  Try just `=WEEKDAY("8/19/2015")` or `=WEEKDAY(DATE(2015,8,19))`.  See [this page](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/weekday.php) too.

Comment: i have full excel document with cells formated like "8/19/2015 0:00". i need to find a way to calculate the day in the week in this format somehow.. do you know how?

Comment: what have you tried? Can you change the formatting to Short Date? You could also use `Left()` if the data is literally what you're showing

Comment: If your formula is really something like `=WEEKDAY(A1)` where `A1` contains what you show, then the problem is that your Windows Regional setting is `DMY` but your data came from a text or CSV file with an `MDY` format.  So 8/19/2015 is really a text string (since there is no 19th month) and WEEKDAY won't work on Text.  If that is correct, your solution will be to properly import the CSV file so the dates are understood by your system

Answer (score 0):

Use the below formula, it should work for you.

```
=WEEKDAY(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Comment: Why does it need the TEXT function?

Comment: @Jeeped The `TEXT` function converts the date to a number format that we provide which will be easier for the `WEEKDAY` function. If the input value is a number, there is no need of this `TEXT` function. There is a chance that the input value could either be as a number or as a string. So this formula works in both the cases.